# aptitude count number of files and directories

Tags: command-line, apt, aptitude

While executing the command `apt (install|remove|update)`, the first line is always `(Reading database ... 266505 files and directories currently installed.)`

I was curious to know which command actually causes this counting? The attempts I have made so far are:

1. `cnt=0;for pkg in $(apt list --installed | tail -n +4 | cut -d '/' -f 1);do cnt=$(($cnt+$(dpkg --listfiles $pkg | wc -l)-1));done`
2. `find /usr/ \( -type f -or -type d \) | wc -l`
   Of course, by varying the path to `/usr` and `/etc`, only `/`, and so on.

None of the counting matches with this. So my questions are:

1. How this counting is done?
2. Is this count stored somewhere? e.g. in `/var/cache/apt-xapian-inedx/`

-- Mike

Comment: The output comes from `dpkg`, which can be confirmed by running `strings $(which dpkg) | grep "currently installed"`. The next step would be looking at the source code of `dpkg` to find out how it calculates the number.

Comment: @Who-so-ever-down-voted, Why downvote? If you dont  like the question, you can ignore it! Is the question so trivial / useless?

Answer (score 1):

The closest result that I could get is using:

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/*.list | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

---

Information of installed packages are located at: `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`.
Each package has a `pkg-name.list` file which contains a list of files located in that package. we can count their line number.

Comment: This number is same as the number I compute using the first command in the original post. You can reproduce it by apt --reinstall install SOME_PKG and then look at the first line.

Comment: I already test it using `--reinstall`, however it didn't gave me any output :)

Comment: finally find it ;) I didn't pay attention first time.

Comment: Here is my output:
`root@my-laptop:~# apt-get install --reinstall bluez
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
OUTPUT_TRUNCATED
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 266505 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bluez_5.43-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking bluez (5.43-0ubuntu1) over (5.43-0ubuntu1) ...
OUTPUT_TRUNCATED
Setting up bluez (5.43-0ubuntu1) ...`

I am talking abt the line that starts with `(Reading...`

Comment: Can't reproduce your results, for me `apt` reports about 400k files and `wc` counts around 1.3M files...

Comment: Working on it, for me it's really close to the real number the different is 30 because of some directories ;)

Comment: Ah, I just saw your edit. Now it's 419042 from `apt` and 419001 from `wc` Close enough, good observation. You could have a look at the `dpkg` source code, https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/src/filesdb.c#n431 is the place where the number is printed, the function https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/src/filesdb.c#n593 is responsible for counting them.

Comment: @ByteCommander I was actaully expecting that there would be some kernel command which would be doing the job. (And also dpkg must be storing it somewhere.) Thanks for the code reference though!